# Circular definition in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef, definition

What I've written is:

```
typedef enum _MyStatus
{
    MY_STATUS_OK = 0,
    MY_STATUS_GENERAL_ERROR = -1,

} MyStatus;

typedef MyStatus (*MyCallback)(MySettings *settings);

typedef struct _MySettings
{
    MyCallback callback;
} MySettings
```

However, it wouldn't compile as when defining MyCallback it doesn't know of MySettings. If I swapped MySettings and MyCallback, it would be the other way round: MySettings wouldn't know of MyCallback.

How generally is this sort of problem handled in C?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can declare an enum this way : `enum MyStatus {
    MY_STATUS_OK = 0,
    MY_STATUS_GENERAL_ERROR = -1,
};

Comment: Yeah, but then I'll always have to write it as `enum MyStatus`, won't I?

Comment: No. I always declare my enums this way, and never sepcify enum when I use them. Maybe it's not that simple in ANSI C, but in modern C++, it just works.

Comment: In C++ is sure to work. It's the same with `structs`. In this way C and C++ differ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about putting this line at the top:

```
typedef struct _MySettings MySettings;
```

This [C FAQ: How can I define a pair of mutually referential structures?](http://c-faq.com/decl/mutrefstructs.html) might be of use.

Comment: Thanks! And instead of `typedef struct _MySettings {...} MySettings;` I should use `struct _MySettings {...};`. Strangely enough, I don't seem to be able to use just `MySettings {...};` though.