# To declare a inner struct consist of reference to the outer struct

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circular definition in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502730/circular-definition-in-c)

```
typedef struct{
  node *next;
  node *last;
} doubleLink;

typedef struct{
 doubleLink doubleLink;
 int data;
} node;
```

The above is a doomed attempt to define an object with a double link.
Placing either typedef before the other would draw a compilation error of "unknown type"
One obvious recourse is to change the pointer type specifier in doubleLink to `void *` 
But I wonder whether there are more "harmless" solutions, say, maybe
I can declare the node struct without defining it?

I'm cognizant that this must be a frequently asked question,  but I don't know by what keyword can I possibly find it.

Comment: search for "forward declaration"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add forward declacation of `node`:

```
struct node;
typedef struct{
  struct node *next;
  struct node *last;
} doubleLink;
```

As you use pointers, you don't need to have this type completely defined before the definition of `doubleLink`.