# Mutually dependent structs in C

Tags: c, struct, enums, unions, forward-declaration

I am following Ruslan Spivak's article series/tutorial "Let's Build A Simple Interpreter", which is a guide for building a simple Pascal interpreter in Python. I am trying to follow along in C. I'm stumped at the part about adding an Abstract Syntax Tree.

I have this header file:

```c
#include "tokens.h"
struct binopnode
{
    struct node left;
    token op;
    struct node right;
};

struct node
{
    union nvalue value;
    enum ntype type;
};

enum ntype
{
    NUM,
    BINOP,
};

union nvalue
{
    struct binopnode binop;
    struct numnode num;
};

struct numnode
{
    token tok;
};
```

where `"tokens.h"` includes the `token` `typedef`'d struct.

My problem is that my compiler:

```
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

throws out `Incomplete Type` errors.

From these links:
http://c-faq.com/decl/mutrefstructs.html
[Circular definition in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502730/circular-definition-in-c)
my guess is that I have to use pointers, but I have absolutely no idea where.

Comment: You must use pointers: `struct node *left` instead of `struct node left`, etc.

Comment: Using `struct node *` in `struct binopnode` is correct. Note that the original: `struct node left` could _not_ compile because the `struct node {` _definition_ would have to precede the `struct binopcode {`. Pointers can be made to _partially_ defined items but full substructs can _not_. That is, how would the compiler know [in a single pass] how much space to allocate for `struct node left` _without_ the _full_ definition of `struct node`?

Comment: You've got _multiple_ ordering problems with the definitions. (e.g.) You try to instantiate a `union nvalue` _inside_ of `struct node` _before_ it's defined [later]. Put the `union nvalue {` _before_ the `struct node {` line. Likewise for almost all of what you're defining. You have to "define it" before you can "use it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare structs first then reference them as pointer later.

In C, when a struct A includes another struct B, A will need memory area for size of B. If struct A includes struct B and struct B includes struct A, compiler can't decide how much memory it should allocate for each structs. So if you want to use structs referencing each other, you should use at least one of them as pointer.

```c
#include "tokens.h"

struct binopnode;
struct node;
enum ntype;
union nvalue;
struct numnode;

struct binopnode
{
    struct node *left;
    token op;
    struct node *right;
};

struct node
{
    union nvalue *value;
    enum ntype type;
};

enum ntype
{
    NUM,
    BINOP,
};

union nvalue
{
    struct binopnode *binop;
    struct numnode *num;
};

struct numnode
{
    token tok;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, objects cannot contain other objects. An object in Python can only contain a *reference* to another object.

Thus, in Python, an object of class `BinOp` contains three references - `self.left`, `self,right`, and `self.op`. But it does not actually contain three objects.

In `C`, a struct can actually contain other structs. So an object (in C, the word "object" just means a region of memory interpreted to be of a particular type - not much like Python objects) of type `struct binop` will contain two objects of type `struct node` as well as one of type `token`.

In C, all types must have a size. Let's find some lower bounds on size (these are only lower bounds because we must take padding into account).

`sizeof(struct binop) >= sizeof(struct node) + sizeof(token) + sizeof(struct node)`

`sizeof(struct node) >= sizeof(union nvalue) + sizeof(enum ntype)`

`sizeof(union nvalue) >= min(sizeof(struct binop), sizeof(struct numnode)) >= sizeof(struct binop)`

So we know that `sizeof(struct binop) >= sizeof(struct node) + sizeof(token) + sizeof(struct node) > sizeof(struct node) >= sizeof(union nvalue) >= sizeof(struct binop)`.

Therefore, `sizeof(struct binop) > sizeof(struct binop)`.

This is a problem, as a number cannot be greater than itself. So `C` cannot compile this code for you because it doesn't know how big a `struct binop` should be.

In fact, any time a `struct` contains itself in this way, with no pointers, this is going to cause a serious issue.

The good news is that we can break the cycle by redefining

```c
union nvalue {
    struct binopnode* binop,
    struct numnode num
}
```

Now, we'll be able to calculate the size of `union nvalue` as `min(sizeof(struct binopnode*), sizeof(struct numnode))`. This is totally fine because pointers have a fixed size (on a 64-bit system, any pointer other than a function pointer will be of size `8` no matter what it's pointing to).